# Concatenating fields in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

consider the following:

```
 <ul class="contracts">
            <li ng-repeat="contract in contracts" class="thumbnail">
                <h3>ID:{{contract.Id}}</a></h3>                    
                <h4>Owner: {{contract.Person.firstName}} {{contract.Person.lastName}}</h4>
           </li>
  </ul>
```

ok, that works, I can display the owner by concatenating the firstName and the lastName. However, it'd be better to have a property FullName somewhere. That property would either return firstname + lastname or 'None' if Person is null.

My problem is that I don't know where to add this property. It feels strange to add it to the contract controller, as it's more related to the Person. But I don't have a Person controller. What would be the approach for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a Contract service

```
angular.factory('Contract', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var Contract = $resource(...);
  ...

  Contract.prototype.getOwner = function() {
    if (this.Person) {
      return this.Person.firstName + this.Person.lastName;
    }
    return 'None';
  }

  return Contract;

}]);
```

You could then use it as

```
<h4>Owner: {{contract.getOwner()}}</h4>
```

Comment: I do have a Contract service and I could do that indeed. Is this a common thing to do ? I know I'm annoying :) But I just want to apply best practices as much as I can from the beginning.

Comment: Check out this repo to see more of this and other approaches used https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app. It seems like a reasonable thing to do. I wouldn't name my properties in PascalCase though (Person vs person)

Comment: Be warned: This function will be evaluated on every $digest. Just put a console.log() inside of it and you'll see. It's generally a better idea to process your Contract or Person object when it changes and update the property rather than use a method like this. It's not *wrong* do to things this way, but it may be less performant, especially in a large repeater.

Comment: It's as performant as `{{contract.Person && contract.Person.firstName + contract.Person.lastName || 'None'}}`, although much more readable. For static bindings, you might want to consider https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce  @blesh

Comment: It sure is. But that's not quite what I'm suggesting. I'm suggesting the concatenation can be done one time at the time the collection (or object) is updated/created.

Comment: And actually, your method will be *more* performant than doing that concatenation in the binding (as per your comment), This is because inside of that repeater (especially prior to 1.2.X), the contents of that are frequently re-$compiled, which reattaches directives and sets up $watches. When a $watch for an expression is set up as the ngBind directive was linked, it would have to lex and parse the expression and build a JS function reference out of it, function reference would be less to parse and lex. ... if only by a little bit. ;)

Comment: In other words, your answer is a good answer, I'm just trying to contributed additional, related information. Have a +1.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant @blesh. But even binding to a pre-concatenated property would still make angular watch for changes on it (to my understanding at least). So you would still need something like `bindonce` to achieve that. (to avoid frequent re-checking)

Comment: Well, checking equality on a property versus executing a function and checking equality on a result are going to have performance differences. Not to mention it's easier to create unintended circumstances when you have a function and you have no idea how often it will be called (depending on what that function is doing internally).